# getJson with custom Flickr API call generates a parse-error

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, getjson, flickr

I spent most of last night trying out the 'getJSON' method in JQuery against the Flickr API. I managed to have a look at some examples from the JQuery docs and managed to make them work, however attempts at reading JSON from my custom API calls failed miserably.

Snippets:

This works:

```
  //JQuery Flickr example code - works!
  $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?&format=json",
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      alert(item.media.m);
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });
```

**This fails!**

```
  //Custom Flickr API Call - nothing?fail?
  $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=c258d8ae4c29bb74da198c6ac3874671&text=Mclaren&per_page=3&format=json&callback=?&nojsoncallback=1",
  function(data) {

    alert(data);


  }).error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + errorThrown); });
```

The second API call is a valid resource, it works in the browser/fiddler and I can see the JSON content, but in my JS code an error is raised

```
"parsererrorError: jQuery18007627279118169099_1345796861535 was not called".
```

At this point I'm stuck, ultimately my end goal is to process the returned JSON and itterate over each 'photo' object in the nested array so that I can easily access their sub properties during iteration like so:

[photo-instance].id

[photo-instance].owner

[photo-instance].secret
etc...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Ref:** http://www.flickr.com/services/api/response.json.html

**Note**: All API keys are for test purposes and will be destroyed soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) :

> If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by
>   the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the
>   discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details.

As your URL contains `callback=?`, the jQuery `getJSON` function is waiting for a (dynamically specified) callback call, JSONP style. But as you specified `nojsoncallback` in the URL, the server sends a standard JSON content as specified in the documentation you provide :

> If you just want the raw JSON, with no function wrapper, add the
>   parameter nojsoncallback with a value of 1 to your request.

Remove the `callback=?` from you URL and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you very much! I removed the callback=? and now I have the objects and can iterate through them (data.photos.photo). I thought JSONP was always used for cross domain ajax? I'm still confused why you would want callback=? in there, why not just retrieve all the data and go from there? thank you again! :)

Comment: You can do cross-domain JSON (not JSONP) if the server accepts it by setting special headers. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control. For modern browsers and servers I think JSONP doesn't make much sense any more but those headers are kindy "new".

Answer (score 0):

Add &nojsoncallback=1 at the end

https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?format=json&nojsoncallback=1